# How to add extra parameters in php $_FILES variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an multiple images upload page. The thing is when am updating the previously uploaded image. The images uploaded before have their own ID on database. So, when I hit update POST not all images out of 5 not set for example.

```
Dump => array(1) {
  ["editproductimages"] => array(5) {
    ["name"] => array(5) {
      [0] => string(0) ""
      [1] => string(11) "desktop.jpg"
      [2] => string(40) "12071419_404680519720527_756783084_n.jpg"
      [3] => string(0) ""
      [4] => string(0) ""
    }
    ["type"] => array(5) {
      [0] => string(0) ""
      [1] => string(10) "image/jpeg"
      [2] => string(10) "image/jpeg"
      [3] => string(0) ""
      [4] => string(0) ""
    }
    ["tmp_name"] => array(5) {
      [0] => string(0) ""
      [1] => string(25) "/opt/lampp/temp/phpYJDIAO"
      [2] => string(25) "/opt/lampp/temp/phpmyxoXB"
      [3] => string(0) ""
      [4] => string(0) ""
    }
    ["error"] => array(5) {
      [0] => int(4)
      [1] => int(0)
      [2] => int(0)
      [3] => int(4)
      [4] => int(4)
    }
    ["size"] => array(5) {
      [0] => int(0)
      [1] => int(55203)
      [2] => int(33773)
      [3] => int(0)
      [4] => int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

The thing I want is to add extract array field inside the **$_FILE**  like to hold their database id on post.

```
["id"] => array(5) {
          [0] => int(10)
          [1] => int(11)
          [2] => int(12)
          [3] => int(14)
          [4] => int(13)
       }
```

is that possible?

Comment: Please post some codes

Comment: Have you tried to submit hidden input's with ids of each image ?

Comment: I dont think adding custom field into `$_FILES` superglobal is possible....as far as I know

Comment: @armen no that doesn help because you still have no mapping that with _FILES with post hidden IDs . did u got me ?

Comment: Yes i got you and initially meant to do it like this as i posted in my answer at bottom

Answer (score 0):

I am not thinking that this is the correct approach or correct answer but I think array_push might help you since $_FILES is also an array.

lets say this is the files data.

```
$filesData = array(
        array('editproductimages'=>array(
                array("name"=>array("","desktop.jpg","12071419_404680519720527_756783084_n.jpg","","")),
                array("type"=> array("","image/jpeg","image/jpeg","","")),
                array("tmp_name"=>array("","/opt/lampp/temp/phpYJDIAO","/opt/lampp/temp/phpmyxoXB","","")),
                array("error"=>array(4,0,0,4,4)),
                array("size"=>array(0,55203,33773,0,0))
            ))
    );
```

then the array($ids) below is what you want to be added.You just need to use array_push to add it.

```
    $ids = array('id'=>array(10,11,12,14,13));
    //actual insertion of $ids to the $filesData variable
    array_push($filesData[0]['editproductimages'],$ids);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($filesData);
    echo '</pre>';
```

I hope that helps

Comment: let see  but , i original wann modify the implemation of the $FILE_ itself so that i can have all the id mapped at post time .

Comment: I dont know why you want to override the implementation of $_FILE since i dont know what you are trying to achieve, my suggestion is do not override it.Though you can also add an input(hidden) for your ids then use the above code to put it in $_FILE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, lets say  you have this form

```
<form action="">
    <!-- For your first image  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="image_ids[]" value="<?php ..place first image id.. ?>" />
    <input type="file" name="image[]"/>

    <!-- For your second image  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="image_ids[]" value="<?php ..place second image id.. ?>" />
    <input type="file" name="image[]"/>

    <!-- For your third image  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="image_ids[]" value="<?php ..place third image id.. ?>" />
    <input type="file" name="image[]"/>

    .....
</form>
```

after submitting this form to php you will have same sequence of values in `$_FILE['image']` and `$_POST['image']` arrays and you can make loop

```
foreach($_POST['image_ids'] as $k => $id){
    // process and save $_FILE['image'][$k] 
    // use $id to save/update necessary values in db
}
```